# Error using heroku_san gem: Your Ruby version is x.x.x, but your Gemfile specified x.x.x (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

After upgrading a Rails application to use Ruby 2.0.0 (from 1.9.3), I started receiving this error when attempting to deploy to Heroku via `rake <stage> deploy`.

```
 Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

It also seems to cause this error, (but I can run the Heroku commands manually without the `heroku_san` helpers, so authorization is not the issue).

```
Expected(200) <=> Actual(401 Unauthorized)
```

I updated the gems to the latest version, and also updated the Heroku Toolbelt.

I found this [pull request](https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san/pull/146) and patched my version, but the error persisted.

How do I solve this (on both Ubuntu & OSX)?

Other info:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64
- Rails 3.2.13
- Ruby 2.0.0-p247
- heroku-api-0.3.15
- heroku_san-4.0.8
- heroku-toolbelt/2.41.0 (x86_64-linux)
- rvm 1.22.10

Comment: This error only seems to be a problem when using RVM.  I did not get the error on a system using rbenv.  Has anyone else noticed this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for me on Ubuntu was to modify

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
```

And change the shebang line to

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Thanks goes to [Pivotal Labs](http://pivotallabs.com/heroku_san-ruby-2-0-and-strfti-me/) for this.

(I don't use a Mac.)

Answer (score 0):

Another issue I found with this error (1.9.2 not 1.9.3) is having BUNDLE_GEMFILE env variable set on heroku which causes heroku ruby build pack to freak and default to 1.9.2.